# Strange behaviour with a repeated function

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a function that:
gets a serialized array out of a database, 
unserializes it, 
adds an item onto the end of the array, 
serializes it 
and updates the database with the new array.

This works fine when I run the function on its own. I can refresh the page and each time it will add an item to the array. When I print_r the array I can see it has added my new item onto the array, assigning it the next available numeric key.

However when I run this function within a foreach loop instead of adding an item on each cycle, it adds an item during the first cycle then every cycle after that it just amends the item that was created in the first cycle.

```
public function updateImage($image, $product_id)
{       
    // Some code here to write the file, not relevant to my question.

    // Process the $image parameter to get $image_src.  
    // The product images are held in an array.

    // Get the serialized array from the database

    $objProduct = $this->Database->prepare("SELECT name, images FROM tl_iso_products WHERE id = ?")->execute($product_id);

    $images = array();

    // Unserialize the result to get the array of images

    $images = unserialize($objProduct->images); 

    // Add the new image to the array   

    $images[] = array(
            'src' => $image_src,
            'alt' => $objProduct->name,
            'link' => '',
            'desc' => '',
            'translate' => '',
    );      

    // Update the database with the new array

    $this->Database->prepare("UPDATE tl_iso_products SET images = ? WHERE id = ?")->execute(serialize($images),$product_id);                        
}
```

This is what the array starts like, with one image:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [src] => image1.jpg
            [alt] => Image alt text
            [link] => 
            [desc] => 
            [translate] => 
        )

)
```

Refresh the page so the function runs a couple of times, changing the image name each time:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [src] => image1.jpg
            [alt] => Image alt text
            [link] => 
            [desc] => 
            [translate] => 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [src] => image2.jpg
            [alt] => Image alt text
            [link] => 
            [desc] => 
            [translate] => 
    )
    [2] => Array
       (
            [src] => image3.jpg
            [alt] => Image alt text
            [link] => 
            [desc] => 
            [translate] => 
      )

)
```

Run the function in a foreach loop, which should have the same effect as above:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
     (
         [src] => image1.jpg
         [alt] => Image alt text
         [link] => 
         [desc] => 
         [translate] => 
     )
  [1] => Array
     (
         [src] => image3.jpg
         [alt] => Image alt text
         [link] => 
         [desc] => 
         [translate] => 
     )
)
```

Instead of adding a new item each time it loops, it adds one new item in the first loop then just overwrites it with each loop after.

Every time it loops it should fetch the array from the database, which will have been updated by the previous loop. Any idea as to why this doesn't happen?

Here's the foreach loop as requested, it runs through an array which contains image urls and the ids of the product they need to be added to:

```
foreach($arrImages as $image)
{
     $this->updateImage($image['url'], $image['product_id']); 
}
```

Comment: can you post your foreach loop?

Comment: Check output of `var_dump($this->Database->prepare("SELECT name, images FROM tl_iso_products WHERE id = ?"))` in every function call. If it returns different ID of object, then this is a query cache of DBMS. If so, you need to disable it because `select` returns cached results every time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i've checked and it returns the same Object ID each time.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, and you probably don't want to hear it, but having to store serialised data in a database is generally a sign of poor design / normalisation. Also the way you are doing this `foreach () { select, amend, update }` is highly inefficient, you should be using a design like `select, foreach() { amend }, update`

Comment: Thanks Leigh, if I could avoid doing it this way I would. Unfortunately i'm working with a system that's already in place so I have to stick to the format it's already in. I see what you mean about it being inefficient but I only need to run this code once to update the system then it'll be done with.